# MySQL PHP select where "X,Y" is in X,Y,Z

Tags: php, mysql, sql, explode, implode

How do I complete this code below? I am trying to `select news` from the database and the `locations` which can be `23,22,88,90` location codes. I know you can just do `IN('23', '22', '88', '90')` but the problem is, my locations are a string so it comes out like `IN('23,22,88,90')` I believe.

How do I expand on the string of locations and select all or any including the locations in the string? So in the database, `newsLocations` could be `22` `23` `22,90` `23,80,90` `90`. If that makes sense? so if `$locationstoGet` has `22,88,90` only, it will get the `newsLocation` even if the result is just `88,90` without the `22`.

```
$locationsToGet = '22,88';
$db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsLocation IN($locationstoGet)");
```

I hope I explained this alright.

Comment: Why don't you normalize your data? That makes many things much easier

Comment: The best way is to normalize the db like nico commented. Other ways that I can think of are using the WHERE ,LIKE combination or using full text search (MATCH, AGAINST) which require full text index.

Comment: it gives more insight if you add db structure in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a response on another site [here](https://bytes.com/topic/mysql/answers/854031-pass-php-array-into-mysql-clause)

So I will adapt the solution there to your scenario. Change locationsToGet into an array, and use the implode function to generate the right syntax for the IN Clause.

```
$locationsToGetArr = array('22','88');
$locations = "'".implode("','",$locationsToGetArr)."'"; //this should output '22','88'
$db->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsLocation IN($locations)");
```

This solution is assuming your database structure is as such

```
+--------+--------------+
|  news  | newsLocation | 
+--------+--------------+
|   1    | 88           | 
|   1    | 22           |
|   2    | 22           |
|   2    | 88           |
+--------+--------------+
```

But if you are storing your data as the following instead

```
    +--------+--------------+
    |  news  | newsLocation | 
    +--------+--------------+
    |   1    | 88,22        | 
    |   2    | 22,88        |
    +--------+--------------+
```

You will not have much choice besides to select all from news table and have PHP filter the location. Not a very efficient method.

Comment: But what if `newsLocations` is `88,22` from the database? Doesn't this only just select if `newsLocations` is either `88` or `22`?

Comment: I am assuming the newsLocation column in news is a single value (i.e. 88, or 22). If you are storing as 88,22 as a whole; then I think you should consider normalizing your database. Otherwise, you may need to select all from the database and filter the data from that column at the application side (e.g. PHP) ; which may be expensive.

Comment: It's extremely important to escape **any and all** data used in the query. In this contrived example it's obvious it's safe, but it that was wired up to `$_POST` data this would create a huge [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If your data is comma separated stored in databse column then you can use MYSQL FIND IN SET as per below example.

SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');

OR you can try with regular expression in MYSQL but it will be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of your locations and then populate your query string with the items from the array

```
$locations = '22,88';
$locationsToGetArray = explode(",", $locationToGet)
$query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsLocation IN(";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($locationsToGetArray); $i++) {
    $query .= $locationsToGetArray[$i];
    if($i == (count($locationToGetArray) - 1)) $query.= ")";
    else $query .= ",";
 }
 $db->query($query);
```

Comment: This is returning `SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsLocation IN(0,1,` for me for some reason

Comment: Try now, I made a mistake, I was adding $i instead of $locationsToGetArray[$i], also if statement is a little bit different, you should put (count($locationToGetArray) -1) into parentheses

Comment: `SELECT * FROM news WHERE newsLocation IN(22,88,` with an extra comma and missing `)`

Comment: I don't understand, it's still doing the same thing as before?

Comment: if statement is a little bit different, you should put (count($locationToGetArray) -1) into parentheses